# Automatically keep current version of config files when apt-get install

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

I need to automatically install a package with its config file already present on the server.

I'm looking for something like:

`apt-get install --yes --force-yes --keep-current-confs mysql-server`

Probably a dumb question but I can't find such an option.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Found the answer on [Raphael Hertzog's Blog](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/) :

```
apt-get install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --force-yes -y mysql-server
```

It's dpkg's role to configure, therefore to chose which conf file to keep.

You can also add this to the config of the system by creating a file in  `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` with this content:

```
Dpkg::Options {
   "--force-confdef";
   "--force-confold";
}
```

Answer (score 23):

On current ubuntu systems you need a bit more:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive ; apt-get dist-upgrade -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --force-yes
```

Comment: Silly question: why do you specify two seemingly mutually exclusive options at the same time?  **confdef** vs **confold**? If this really works that's surely just a matter of the evaluation order? Not that I tried it ...

Comment: "--force-confold: do not modify the current configuration file, the new version is installed with a .dpkg-dist suffix. With this option alone, even configuration files that you have not modified are left untouched. You need to combine it with --force-confdef to let dpkg overwrite configuration files that you have not modified."

Comment: `--force-yes` should be used as a last resort as it has the opportunity to break your system! [Please visit this mange page for details on using the --allow switches](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-get.8.en.html).

Comment: The --allow-* flags were introduced in a version released after my initial reply :) Though people today should better use them in favor of the --force-yes  flag.

Comment: Seven years later, how do people view the use of "export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive" these days?  Good idea?  Bad idea?

Comment: Seems like all you really need is `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

Comment: @BrentBaccala That is not accurate, on Ubuntu  you still need the dpkg options this answer lists.